# kubectl output different than remote API

Tags: rest, kubernetes, ctl

I am using kubernetes for container orchestration,I dont get any output while running `kubectl get rc` on the master node while I get a list of replication controllers when using their REST API

```
curl -X GET masterurl/api/v1/replicationcontrollers.
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, kubectl only shows resources that are in the `default` namespace, whereas that REST endpoint will return replication controllers from all namespaces.

To get the same output from kubectl, run it with the `--all-namespaces` flag, as in `kubectl get rc --all-namespaces`.

If you only want kubectl to return resources from a particular namespace `foo` that isn't `default`, you can use `--namespace=foo`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you mentioned, Alex.  I think /api/v1/replicationcontrollers means give me the RCs in the default namespace.   EDIT- You are correct.  I was making a mistake.